# How to use an arbitrary function as a model in RapidMiner

Tags: rapidminer

I'd like to use a custom function (a linear combination of attributes in my case) as a model in RapidMiner to compare with other models. To be specific, I want to use the "default" model in cross-validation to compare with other models with the same settings. How can I accomplish that?

I'd like a model learner operator that discards all inputs and output a user specified function as a model. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely possible. Rapidminer allows you to create your own extension, and operator.

https://docs.rapidminer.com/developers/creating-your-own-extension/

Comment: Writing your own extension is definitely an option. Also feel free to ask further, or re-post, questions in the RapidMiner community forum (http://community.rapidminer.com).